# what is this error in IOS Flutter Project?

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-m1

My macbook is m1 mac book

and i want to run flutter project

in android is working done

but in IOS saw me error code

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available'
/Users/idong-gi/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7/ios/Classes/Types/UserScript.swift:12:5
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
idong-gi@idong-gis-MacBook-Pro xeta_app %

my another intel core mac book is run with android, ios

please help me!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've simply fixed it by updating the platform to iOS 14 in Podfile.

Answer (score 0):

Change the version
platform :ios, '14.0'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).